# kafka Old consumer_offsets are not getting deleted

Tags: apache-kafka

`Kafka Version 0.10.1.1`

The brokers are having all the log cleanup/retention defaults:

```
log.cleanup.policy=delete
log.retention.hours=168 (7 days)
offsets.retention.minutes=1440 (1 day)
log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760 (10M)
```

But I can see the `__consumer_offsets` from Jul 6:

```
[root@npe-tfb-kfk-w2b-b3 __consumer_offsets-13]# ls -ltr -h
total 71M
-rw-r-----. 1 root root 70M Jul  6 08:31 00000000000081206436.log
-rw-r-----. 1 root root 10M Jul 26 12:10 00000000000081206436.index
-rw-r-----. 1 root root 10M Jul 26 12:10 00000000000081206436.timeindex
```

In Production I can see `consumer_offsets .log` file from Jul 16.

How is this possible? If I manually delete the old `.log`, `.index` and `.timeindex` files, is that going to impact the stability of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The date discrepancy here is likely because of a restart with an unclean shutdown. The index files are rebuilt on such cases. As far as your offsets topic goes, you shouldn't manually deleted it unless you know for sure that's what you want. It will potentially cause a loss of state for your consumers. The topic is compacted and you don't have much data in it at all. I expect that you have previously deleted segments before because I don't see log segment 0 there. Just make sure your log cleaner is still functional and you will be ok. If you are worried about disk space because of a 70MB log segment, then you need more disk. Kafka disks should be 100s of GB in size.

Comment: The above example is from a lower env. In Prod I see that `consumer_offsets` from `Jul 10 - Jul 26` is present but the topic logs from `Jul 22` is only present. This makes me think any `offsets` between `Jul 10 - Jul 21` doesn't make any difference. I never deleted these `offsets` file manually and that's why I wanted to check with community, what if I delete those. Still not sure why `log.cleanup.policy` will not work though.

Comment: log.cleanup.policy will apply as the default policy for new topics. A cleanup.policy is applied on a per topic basis. You could theoretically apply a delete policy to the offsets topic but I wouldn't recommend it. That's a good way to lose offsets or end up with weird consumer behavior. fwiw I do recommend in the future you post data that matches the description. The problem is more straightforward to look at if it's consistently described.